# Packaging django app that includes management commands

Tags: python, django, setuptools, django-management-command

I am working on a django app that includes a custom management command. This app should be packed for pip.

Layout of the app is standard

```
django-simpl_ssg
   simple_ssg 
       management
          commands
              __init__.py
              testcommand.py
       migrations
           __init__.py
       __init__.py
       admin.py
       ....

   setup.cfg
   setup.py
   pyproject.toml
```

based on django 4.0 docu setup.cfg is setup like this

```
....
[options]
include_package_data = true
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.8
install_requires =
    Django >= 3.2  # Replace "X.Y" as appropriate
```

Now the problem is when running `python setup.py sdist` the app gets packaged but the management command is omitted

`````
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to django_simple_ssg.egg-info/requires.txt
writing django_simple_ssg.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to django_simple_ssg.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to django_simple_ssg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'django_simple_ssg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'django-simple_ssg/static'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'django-simple_ssg/templates'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'django-simple_ssg/docs'
writing manifest file 'django_simple_ssg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating django-simple_ssg-0.1
creating django-simple_ssg-0.1/django_simple_ssg.egg-info
creating django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
creating django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg/migrations
copying files to django-simple_ssg-0.1...
copying LICENSE -> django-simple_ssg-0.1
copying MANIFEST.in -> django-simple_ssg-0.1
copying README.md -> django-simple_ssg-0.1
copying setup.cfg -> django-simple_ssg-0.1
copying setup.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1
copying django_simple_ssg.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/django_simple_ssg.egg-info
copying django_simple_ssg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/django_simple_ssg.egg-info
copying django_simple_ssg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/django_simple_ssg.egg-info
copying django_simple_ssg.egg-info/requires.txt -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/django_simple_ssg.egg-info
copying django_simple_ssg.egg-info/top_level.txt -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/django_simple_ssg.egg-info
copying simple_ssg/__init__.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/admin.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/apps.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/content.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/models.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/smpl_tmplt_lng.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/tests.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/views.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg
copying simple_ssg/migrations/__init__.py -> django-simple_ssg-0.1/simple_ssg/migrations
Writing django-simple_ssg-0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'django-simple_ssg-0.1' (and everything under it)````

Any hint is welcome 

Thanks a lot
`````

Comment: I think it's because you're missing `__init__.py` in the `management` directory (you've only added it to `management/commands`.

Comment: great this is what I forgot. Thanks a lot!